# How to get the frontend blocks when i in backend?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When i write in backend this code i get **bool(false)**. I understand that mean that no block with type 'page/html', but how to get the frontend active blocks when i in backend?

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('page/html');
Zend_Debug::dump($layout);
```

Comment: Just to clarify by your comment below, are you trying to get the frontend block collection and filter by whats active?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html');
Zend_Debug::dump($block);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i want to get name or type of frontend block area when i in backend. Your code create block, but i needed a list of frontend block, how it's possible to get?